# Loading 8-bit grayscale image using ImageIO

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I want to load a 8-bit grayscale image using `grayscaleImage = ImageIO.read(grayscaleFile)`. However, the `BufferedImage` class (which is the type of `grayscaleImage`) only provides a method `getRGB(int x, int y)`. So, what are the values of `color.getRed()`, `color.getGreen()`, `color.getBlue()` and `color.getAlpha()` where

```
Color color = new Color(grayscaleImage.getRGB(x, y), true);
```

From a first observation, it seems like the 8-bit value, stored in the image file at pixel `(x,y)`, is propagated into the red, green and blue component of `color` while it's alpha value is fixed at `255`.

Can someone confirm this observation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that is obtained with `image.getRGB(x,y)` is an `int` that consists of the three color components Red, Green and Blue, each having 8 bit. The Alpha value is fixed as 255 when the image does not contain transparency.

When the image is a grayscale image, the Red, Green and Blue components of this RGB value will be all equal. So you can obtain the "gray" value as

```
int rgb = image.getRGB(x,y);

// This yields a value between 0 (black)
// and 255 (white) :
int gray = rgb & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right. A gray color is just a color with same value in three color's components (red, green, blue). Although you only need one value to determine the color (because red, green and blue components have the same value), at image loading that value is assign to all three color components.

If you get the value for each pixel of the image, you must obtain the same value for three color's components for the same pixel x,y. For alpha component, as it's a grayscale image, is correct it be at 255.